# setStatusBarHidden(_:withAnimation:) deprecated in iOS 9

Tags: ios, swift, ios9, statusbar

I see that in iOS 9 `setStatusBarHidden(_:withAnimation:)` is now deprecated and the documentation says to use `[UIViewController prefersStatusBarHidden]` instead but what is the alternative in iOS 9 if I still want to hide the status bar with a slide animation?

Answer (score 101, accepted):

Refer to `preferredStatusBarUpdateAnimation`,

Gif

[image]

Code

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var isHidden:Bool = false{
        didSet{
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5) { () -> Void in
                self.setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()
            }  
         }
    }
    @IBAction func clicked(sender: AnyObject) {
        isHidden = !isHidden
    }
    override var preferredStatusBarUpdateAnimation: UIStatusBarAnimation{
        return .slide
    }
    override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool{
        return isHidden
    }
 }
```

Comment: Mine's not animating even though it's in a aim block. Any ideas?

Comment: Does it work with "View controller-based status bar appearance" = NO?

Comment: Have not test,but I guess not work when this key is NO

Comment: Mime works after set "View controller-based status bar appearance" = YES. Thank you!

Comment: Worked for me too, major thanks for the animate(withDuration:) tip. I am surprised to know .slide does not animate implicitly over a period of time.

Comment: if you need `View controller-based status bar appearance` = NO, this might help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/41294874/611879

Answer (score 14):

**Swift 3**

- Computed variables have replaced some functions
- The animate function has updated syntax

---

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var isHidden:Bool = false
    @IBAction func clicked(sender: AnyObject) {
        isHidden = !isHidden
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5) { () -> Void in
            self.setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()
        }
    }

    override var preferredStatusBarUpdateAnimation: UIStatusBarAnimation {
        return UIStatusBarAnimation.slide
    }
    override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {
        return isHidden
    }
}
```

Answer (score 13):

I have cleaned up **Leo's** amazing answer a bit by moving the update to `didSet` (**Swift 3** syntax).

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBAction func clicked(sender: AnyObject) {
        statusBarHidden = !statusBarHidden
    }

    var statusBarHidden = false {
        didSet {
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5) { () -> Void in
                self.setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()
            }
        }
    }

    override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {
        return statusBarHidden
    }

    override var preferredStatusBarUpdateAnimation: UIStatusBarAnimation {
        return .slide
    }
}
```

Comment: I wish I would remember to use didSet from time to time... I'm just used to my old ways of coding, but this is sooooooo much better :)

Answer (score 4):

if you are coding with objective c, Here is the solution :)(Leo's Objective C version :P thanks man!!!)

declare a variable

```
bool isHidden;
isHidden = false;//in viewDidload()
```

and then add this code when you want to hide status bar

```
isHidden = true;
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.6 animations:^{
    [self performSelector:@selector(setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate)];
}];
```

after that add this two method

```
-(UIStatusBarAnimation) preferredStatusBarUpdateAnimation
{
return UIStatusBarAnimationFade;
}

-(BOOL) prefersStatusBarHidden
{ return isHidden;}
```

Hope your problem will be solve (smile)

Answer (score 0):

- **SWIFT 3 ALTERNATIVE**

Hey guys, found a much neater way of going about it for Swift 3, by using a private var pairing with each of the overrides. 
My original post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42083459/7183483

but here's the jist of it:

Here's a snippet:

```
override var preferredStatusBarUpdateAnimation: UIStatusBarAnimation {
    get {
        return .slide
    }
}

private var statusBarStyle : UIStatusBarStyle = .default

override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
    get {
        return statusBarStyle
    }
}

private var statusBarStatus : Bool = false

override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {
    get {
        return statusBarStatus
    }
}
```

which I then could call in a function like so: (this is one of my examples, so disregard the custom function).

```
func sliderView(sliderView: SliderView, didSlideToPlace: CGFloat, within: CGFloat) {

    let val = (within - (didSlideToPlace - sliderView.upCent))/(within)
    print(val)
    //Where you would change the private variable for the color, for example.
    if val > 0.5 {
        statusBarStyle = .lightContent
    } else {
        statusBarStyle = .default
    }
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: {
        sliderView.top.backgroundColor = UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(val)
        self.coverLayer.alpha = val
        self.scroll.backgroundColor = colors.lightBlueMainColor.withAlphaComponent(val)
    }, completion: {
        value in
        //If you do not call setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate() in an animation block, the animation variable won't be called it seems.
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.4, animations: {

            self.animating = true

            //Where you set the status for the bar (your part of the solution)
            self.statusBarStatus = false

            //Then you call for the refresh
            self.setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()
        })
    })
}
```

Comment: This is a great solution. I did not think of making the status hidden flag dynamic.