# status bar hidden in modal view (over fullscreen presentation)

Tags: ios, hidden, statusbar, modalviewcontroller

try to hide the status bar from a modal view.

already check several methods:

```
override func prefersStatusBarHidden() -> Bool {
    return true
}

with / without self.setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()
```

also

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().setStatusBarHidden(true, withAnimation: .Fade)
```

but depreciated in iOS 9

this works in fullscreen presentation (modal segue presentation option) but note in over full screen which is my setting.

if you have any idea..

Comment: Please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32808593/setstatusbarhidden-withanimation-deprecated-in-ios-9, which I think addresses your issue.

Comment: hi, thanks but same issue. works on full screen presentation but not on over full screen setting..

Comment: First go to plist and check if View controller-based status bar appearance is set to YES and set prefersStatusBarHidden() which you've tried.

Comment: same issue, but thanks.

Answer (score 58):

For a **non-fullscreen** presentation of a View Controller, you need to use the `modalPresentationCapturesStatusBarAppearance` property.

e.g.

```
toViewController.modalTransitionStyle = .coverVertical
toViewController.modalPresentationStyle = .overFullScreen
toViewController.modalPresentationCapturesStatusBarAppearance = true

fromViewController.present(toViewController,
            animated: true,
            completion: nil)
```

For a **fullscreen** presentation of a View Controller, you need to:

1. set the new VC's `modalPresentationStyle`.
2. override `prefersStatusBarHidden` in the new VC
3. set your app plist `UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance` value to YES

e.g.

```
toViewController.modalTransitionStyle = .coverVertical
toViewController.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen

fromViewController.present(toViewController,
            animated: true,
            completion: nil)
```

(Yes, status bar setting in iOS is pitifully bad. It's no wonder Stack Overflow has so many questions on the subject, and so many varied answers.)

Comment: Is `.coverVertical ` necessary?

Comment: No, it's the default value

Answer (score 8):

To hide the status bar when doing an over full screen modal, you need to set this in viewDidLoad:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()    
    modalPresentationCapturesStatusBarAppearance = true
}
```

Then do the standard method to hide status bar:

```
override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {
    return true
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Indeed for `FullScreen` status bar update called automatically, but not for `OverFullScreen`.

Furthermore in my case i was need to deal with navigation controller in stack, to pass **ModalViewController** as child:

```
extension UINavigationController {

    public override func childViewControllerForStatusBarHidden() -> UIViewController? {
        return self.visibleViewController
    }

    public override func childViewControllerForStatusBarStyle() -> UIViewController? {
        return self.visibleViewController
    }
}
```

Inside **ModalViewController** we manually update status bar, also in order to make it smooth we have to do that in `viewWillDisappear`, but at that point `visibleViewController` still **ModalViewController**, nothing left as to use internal bool statusBarHidden and update it accordingly

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    self.statusBarHidden = true
    self.setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()
}
override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    self.statusBarHidden = false
    self.setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()
}
override func prefersStatusBarHidden() -> Bool {
    return self.statusBarHidden
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a storyboard and you want to hide/show the status bar, you can use this method on previous view controller:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
      UIApplication.shared.setStatusBarHidden(false, with: UIStatusBarAnimation.none)
}
```